# How to find liapunov number of system

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, bifurcation

My book has the given example:

The quadratic system
\begin{align*}\
\dot{x}&=\mu x-y+x^2\\
\dot{y}&=x+\mu y+x^2
\end{align*}
has a weak focus of multiplicity at the origin for $\mu=0$ since the Liapunov number $\sigma=-3\pi\neq 0$\

I was wondering if someone could help explain to me how they arrive at the $\sigma=-3\pi$?

My book has a formula for the liapunov number, which I am assuming they used for the calculation.
It is as follows:
$$\sigma=\frac{3\pi}{2b}\{[3(a_{30+b_{03}})+(a_{12}+b_{21})]-\frac{1}{b}[2(a_{20}b_{20}-a_{02}b_{02})-a_{11}(a_{02}+a_{20})+b_{11}(b_{02}+b_{20})]\}$$
Where
$$p(x,y)=\sum_{i+j\geq 2}a_{ij}x^iy^j \quad \text{and} \quad q(x,y)=\sum_{i+j\geq 2}b_{ij}x^iy^j$$
But I am having diffuctly understanding how to use this formula?

All of the examples I have seen are similar to this, where they only give the result and not the calculation.
Can someone help me understand, how exactly I am supposed to use the formula for the calculation?

I am also interested in the difference of calculating the liapunov number in 2d and 3d?

Any help is appreciated! :)

Comment: Is it actually $…+x^2$ in both equations, or should the second be $…+y^2$? What is $b$ in the general formulation? Is the general system $\dot x = ax+by-p(x,y)$, $\dot y=-bx+ay+q(x,y)$?

Answer (score 1):

You have $p(x,y)=x^2$, so $a_{2,0}=1$, all other $a_{i,j}=0$. Likewise $q(x,y)=x^2$ giving $b_{2,0}=0$, the rest zero.

With $b=1$ the formula evaluates directly to $\sigma=-3\pi$, which presumably means that the solutions spiral inwards, as that would be the natural calibration of $σ$.

Empirically $r(t)^{-2}-r_0^{-2}\approx 0.5(t-t_0)$, so the motion is indeed a spiral inwards. I can't imagine what the connection to $\sigma$ would be.